# Choosing WiFi Router/Repeater Antennas: Gain vs Directionality + Combinations

Tags: networking, router, power, antenna, wireless-extender

My apartment complex offers free WiFi, and the landlord has said I may use it from my apartment, but the signal is quite weak. I would like to get a range extender to pick up the distant signal but then make it optimally available to my small apartment.

1. It is my understanding that a higher gain omnidirectional antenna connects better with distant connections whereas a lower gain omnidirectional antenna provides better coverage to its immediate vicinity.
2. It is also my understanding that an extender has a fixed power output which is shared amongst all antennas. As such, increasing total antenna dBi decreases the strength of the signal projected.

Given an 802.11ac extender with three antennas, is it better to:

- Use three 2dbi antennas
- Use three 5dbi antennas
- Use three 9dbi antennas
- Use a combination of antennas (2-5-9, 5-9-9, 2-9-9, etc.)
- Something else?

And, how should the antennas be positioned?

Comment: Is the apartments wifi "ac"?  If not an "ac" extender won't make it "ac".

Comment: I doubt that it is. My ac extender is more an investment in the future. As for now, I'm less concerned about speed and more about signal strength/reliability.

Comment: Then I wouldn't go AC, get a 2.4 ghz repeater with hi-gain antennas.  Invest in the future in the future in this case.